# How to set autocomplete selected item with gray background?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-4

I work on asp.net mvc call api using ajax jquery . I face issue on design auto complete

My issue auto complete selected item not display with gray background

I don't know how to do that

my code details

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  
        $("#txtLineManagerId").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var searchText = $("#txtLineManagerId").val();
                console.log("search text" + searchText)
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEmployeeBasedSearchText", "Resignation")',
                    data: { searchText: searchText },
                    method: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                         
                            return { label: item.EmployeeID + " - " + item.EmployeeName + " - " + item.Designation , value: item.EmployeeID, employeeName: item.EmployeeName };

                        }))

                    }
                });
            },
            position: { my: "right top", at: "right bottom" },
            appendTo: '#searchContainer',
            select: function (event, ui) { 
                $("#LineManagerName").val(ui.item.employeeName);
    
            },
            minLength: 4,
        
        });

         <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LineManager, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "txtLineManagerId" } })
                    <div id="searchContainer">

                    </div>
                 
                </div>
 <div class="col-md-7">

                  
  </div>
```

sample for expected result  I need

[image: selection with gray color expected]

scripts used to make autocomplete working

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"
        language="javascript"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: First of all, there is a ton of different "autocomplete" scripts out there - so please explicitly mention, which one you are using here. Second, if that element you are interested in already has a border applied to it in this situation, then there is probably a good chance, that that happens via a _class_ the element is given - so that's the very first thing I would check for here, using your browser dev tools.

Comment: ok great can you show me how to do that please by code

Comment: what different you mean i added control managerid and jquery ajax applied

Comment: Browser devtools aren't accessed 'by code' in this instance. Find out how to access them for your particular browser and using the inspect facility look to see exactly what CSS and what classes are already applied to the element you are interested in.

Comment: _"what different you mean"_ - there is not one single, "ultimate" autocomplete library out there - there are lots of different ones, and they all have their differences. From just the code you have posted so far, we can not tell _which_ autocomplete library you are using. Could be https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/, could be https://github.com/Honatas/bootstrap-4-autocomplete - or one of hundreds, if not thousand different ones that can be found on the internet. So _you_ need to tell us, which one you are actually using there.

Comment: i applied autocomplete scripts as you told me check my original updated post

Comment: Why would you be embedding _three_ different versions of the same library? You got jQuery UI there in version 1.10.3, 1.8.9 and 1.12.0 in there - that is the very _first_ thing you should fix. Embedding multiple different versions of one library, that is asking for trouble.

Comment: so tell me what i change please and i will do

Comment: _"sample for expected result I need"_ - so this isn't what you currently have already then? That extra border around that first option there, isn't actually a thing you currently already have? I was wondering about that already ... Because right now, it does not look as if you _had_ any "selected" option there. The field content is `1234`, so _all_ of those shown options are valid choices at this point. And when the user clicks one of them _to_ select it, the dropdown will close afterwards. (So not sure what _effect_ a changed background color for the selected option should still have then?)

Comment: so what i do to solve that please

Comment: so can you please show to me what i do